# C# exception when modifying database with EntityFramework (Sqlite)

Tags: c#, .net

developers. I'm a begginer so please excuse me if I don't know how to explain. So I have this code sample into another class:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public string DbPath { get; }

    public BloggingContext()
    {
        var folder = Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData;
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
        DbPath = System.IO.Path.Join(path, "blogging.db");
    }

    // The following configures EF to create a Sqlite database file in the
    // special "local" folder for your platform.
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");
}
 

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string? Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; } = new();
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog? Blog { get; set; }
}
```

All i want is to modify the database using Sqlite, this is my Main method:

```
using var db = new BloggingContext();
Console.WriteLine($"Database Path: {db.DbPath}");
//Create
Console.WriteLine("Insert a new blog");
db.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet" });
db.SaveChanges();
//Read
Console.WriteLine("Querying for a blog");
var blog = db.Blogs
    .OrderBy(b => b.BlogId)
    .First();
//Update
Console.WriteLine("Updating the blog");
blog.Url = "www.blablabla.com";
blog.Posts.Add(new Post { Title = "My first post", Content = "Playing with EntityFramework" });
db.SaveChanges();
//Delete
Console.WriteLine("Deleting what we created");
db.Remove(blog);
db.SaveChanges();
```

However, the app crashes and it's giving me the following exception:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
Message=An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational

Inner Exception 1:
SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Blogs'.

I would like to know how to fix the issue, I've been looking everywhere but I couldn't find anything wrong. Any advice is helpful. Thanks a lot!

Tried installing all types of packages, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner exception says what's the real problem: "SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Blogs'.". So it says that the table "blogs" doesn't exist in your database. A key concept of entity framework are migrations.

> When a data model change is introduced, the developer uses EF Core
> tools to add a corresponding migration describing the updates
> necessary to keep the database schema in sync. ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli))

So you need to create a new migration (if you haven't done that already) and update the database.